# how to detect strings that end with a number

Tags: c#, string, parsing

i am trying to parse out a string and in some cases there is an extra " - [some number]" at the end.  for example,

instead of showing

```
 Technologist
```

it shows

```
Technologist - 23423
```

i dont want to just check or split on "-" because there are other names that do have a "-" in them

can anyone think of a clean way of removing this extra noise so:

**Technologist - 23423** resolves to **Technologist**

Comment: Does `Technologist - 2 - 12345` resolve to `Technologist - 2` or `Technologist`?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta  - i am not going to have this case (because i know my data) but to be complete:  If i had  Technologist-Specialist - 234234 i would want it to resolve to Technologist-Specialist.  I would never have two sets of number noise at the end like in your example

Comment: So, remove all data after the last space-dash combo, if that combo is present? Or maybe remove all data after the last dash, and space-trim the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case regular expressions, such as @" - \d+$" in this case. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Tidy("Technologist - 12345");
        Tidy("No trailing stuff");
        Tidy("A-B1 - 1 - other things");
    }

    private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"- \d+$");

    static void Tidy(string text)
    {
        string tidied = regex.Replace(text, "");
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' => '{1}'", text, tidied);
    }
}
```

Note that this currently *doesn't* spot negative numbers. If you wanted it to, you could use

```
new Regex(@"- -?\d+$");
```

Comment: how would i go about checking if i need to do a tidy.  I guess i can call Tidy on all my records and it would just do nothing on the other ones.

Comment: @ooo: Yup, and that would be simpler than checking whether or not you needed to tidy, and then doing so only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
var strRegex = @"\s*-\s*\d+$";

var regex = new Regex(strRegexs);

var strTargetString = "Technologist - 23423";

var res = myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, "");
```

This will work on the following strings (all is evaluating to `Text`):

```
Text - 34234
Text -1
Text    -     342
Text-3443
```