# c# How to trim string and check it it ends with numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to use regular expression and check for a given string if it ends with numbers

```
asdf4-24rwefaw-234tefg-teer6666
wert34-g54g5-345g345-25trv3457
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect strings that end with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858474/how-to-detect-strings-that-end-with-a-number)

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

Since you removed the optional whitespace from the end of the string,

```
var correct = char.IsDigit(yourString.Last());
```

would suffice.

--

you could do

```
var correct = char.IsDigit(yourString.TrimEnd().Last());
```

as a alternartive to the `Regex`.

---

or perhaps,

```
var correct = char.IsDigit(yourString.Reverse()
        .First(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

---

If you want to do it repeatedly, the `Regex` is the way to go. Once its instantiated, I suspect it will be faster.

Comment: I cannot find the IsNumber() method. Where is it defined?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov Check now

Comment: @AnarKhalilov, that was fail, must be some other language, corrected now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
                                                  +-- a digit
                                                  |
                                                  |   +-- end of string
                                                 -+   |
Regex.Match("asdf4-24rwefaw-234tefg-teer6666", @"\d\s*$").Success
                                                   -+-
                                                    |
                                                    +-- zero or more whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "asdf4-24rwefaw-234tefg-teer6666";
bool endsWithNumber = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\d$");
```